# SNMP agent in c#

Tags: c#, snmp

I am looking for various solutions for creating SNMP agent in c#. I found several companies that offer some products, but most of them use their own server. However, I found one solution that uses an agent extension.

Two questions:

1. Does anyone know other solutions in c# that use the framework of the SNMP service and create an extension agent?
2. Does someone knows about a tool that convert mib files to C# classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to write extension to Microsoft SNMP agent, it may not support C# assemblies,

[CodeProject article on this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SNMP_Agent_DLL__Part1_.aspx)

If in fact you try to extend another SNMP agent, of course you should go to its vendor for assistance. Only the MIB to C# convertor provided by this vendor can be used to develop extensions for that agent.

Answer (score 0):

[AgenPro](http://www.agentpp.com/download.html) is a tool which can generate code from MIBs.
But it generates stubs in Java to be used with the SNMP4J-Agent library.

You may try it out, to get a feel of an SNMP-agent.